# Grafana Promql histogram quantile query issue

Tags: histogram, prometheus, grafana, quantile, promql

I am trying to plot the TP99 for all the models that do not start with the word "test".

So I created the following query:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, 
    sum by (m_application)(
        rate( 
            model_execution_duration_seconds_percentile_bucket{
                m_account="test-account-number", kubernetes_cluster="cluster01", m_application!~"^(test).*", method="POST"
            }[5m]
        )
    ) 
    by (le, m_application)
)
```

I am certain that the inner query is correct which plots the rate for all the models that do not start with the pattern `test*` (has been verified).

The error I am receiving is `"1:279: parse error: unexpected <by>"`. Not exactly sure what I should do to fix this issue. Could someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

you have two by clauses in your query:

```
histogram_quantile(0.99, 
    sum by (m_application)(   <------------ here is the first
        rate( 
            model_execution_duration_seconds_percentile_bucket{
                m_account="test-account-number", kubernetes_cluster="cluster01", m_application!~"^(test).*", method="POST"
            }[5m]
        )
    ) 
    by (le, m_application)  <------------ here is the second
)
```

Please note, you also need to aggregate by `le` in order to calculate the histogram. So removing the first one will solve your problem.